# C# minimize statetement

Tags: c#

How do I minimize the code below:

```
if (sort == "none")
{
    var notes = partial.OrderBy(x => x.Rank).OrderBy(x => x.Stat).OrderByDescending(x => x.Note_Strength_Value).Skip(startIndex).Take(BlockSize).ToList();
    NoteList.Clear();
    if (notes.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in notes)
        {
            NoteList.Add(new NoteModel
            {
                Note1 = "<tr id=\"" + item.ID + "\" class=\"trPregame\"><td style=\"text-align:left; width:100%;\" id=\"notesonly\">" + item.Note1 + "</td></tr>",
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NoteList.Add(new NoteModel
        {
            Note1 = "<tr id=\"noresult\"><td colspan=\"1\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>No Results Found!</b></td></tr>"
        });
    }
}

if (sorttype == "Note")
{
    if (sort == "ascending")
    {
        IList<NoteModel2> partial3 = new List<NoteModel2>();
        foreach (var i in partial)
        {
            partial3.Add(new NoteModel2
            {
                ID = i.ID,
                Note1 = i.Note1,
                Note2 = Regex.Replace(i.Note1.Trim(), @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty),
                Rank = (int)i.Rank
            });
        }
        var notes = partial3.OrderBy(x => x.Note2).Skip(startIndex).Take(BlockSize).ToList();
        NoteList.Clear();
        if (notes.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in notes)
            {
                NoteList.Add(new NoteModel
                {
                    Note1 = "<tr id=\"" + item.ID + "\" class=\"trPregame\"><td style=\"text-align:left; width:100%;\" id=\"notesonly\">" + item.Note1 + "</td></tr>",
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NoteList.Add(new NoteModel
            {
                Note1 = "<tr id=\"noresult\"><td colspan=\"1\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>No Results Found!</b></td></tr>"
            });
        }
    }

    if (sort == "descending")
    {
        IList<NoteModel2> partial3 = new List<NoteModel2>();
        foreach (var i in partial)
        {
            partial3.Add(new NoteModel2
            {
                ID = i.ID,
                Note1 = i.Note1,
                Note2 = Regex.Replace(i.Note1.Trim(), @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty),
                Rank = (int)i.Rank
            });
        }
        var notes = partial3.OrderByDescending(x => x.Note2).Skip(startIndex).Take(BlockSize).ToList();
        NoteList.Clear();
        if (notes.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in notes)
            {
                NoteList.Add(new NoteModel
                {
                    Note1 = "<tr id=\"" + item.ID + "\" class=\"trPregame\"><td style=\"text-align:left; width:100%;\" id=\"notesonly\">" + item.Note1 + "</td></tr>",
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NoteList.Add(new NoteModel
            {
                Note1 = "<tr id=\"noresult\"><td colspan=\"1\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>No Results Found!</b></td></tr>"
            });
        }
    }
}


//SORT BY RANK
if (sorttype == "Rank")
{
    if (sort == "ascending")
    {
        IList<NoteModel2> partial3 = new List<NoteModel2>();
        foreach (var i in partial)
        {
            partial3.Add(new NoteModel2
            {
                ID = i.ID,
                Note1 = i.Note1,
                Note2 = Regex.Replace(i.Note1.Trim(), @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty),
                Rank = (int)i.Rank
            });
        }
        var notes = partial3.OrderBy(x => x.Rank).Skip(startIndex).Take(BlockSize).ToList();
        NoteList.Clear();
        if (notes.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in notes)
            {
                NoteList.Add(new NoteModel
                {
                    Note1 = "<tr id=\"" + item.ID + "\" class=\"trPregame\"><td style=\"text-align:left; width:100%;\" id=\"notesonly\">" + item.Note1 + "</td></tr>",
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NoteList.Add(new NoteModel
            {
                Note1 = "<tr id=\"noresult\"><td colspan=\"1\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>No Results Found!</b></td></tr>"
            });
        }
    }

    if (sort == "descending")
    {
        IList<NoteModel2> partial3 = new List<NoteModel2>();
        foreach (var i in partial)
        {
            partial3.Add(new NoteModel2
            {
                ID = i.ID,
                Note1 = i.Note1,
                Note2 = Regex.Replace(i.Note1.Trim(), @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty),
                Rank = (int)i.Rank
            });
        }
        var notes = partial3.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rank).Skip(startIndex).Take(BlockSize).ToList();
        NoteList.Clear();
        if (notes.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in notes)
            {
                NoteList.Add(new NoteModel
                {
                    Note1 = "<tr id=\"" + item.ID + "\" class=\"trPregame\"><td style=\"text-align:left; width:100%;\" id=\"notesonly\">" + item.Note1 + "</td></tr>",
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NoteList.Add(new NoteModel
            {
                Note1 = "<tr id=\"noresult\"><td colspan=\"1\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>No Results Found!</b></td></tr>"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Are there other way to minimize the code or to optimize it?

The sorts are:

- none as default sort notes by Note Strength Value in descending, Stat and Rank in ascending order.
- ascending
- descending

And sorttypes:

- Note
- Rank

Thanks

Comment: Check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com - but come up with a better title and look through their faq before posting anything.

Comment: This *would* be an ok post on CR, **if** you added a plain-English description of what the code is doing, along with sufficient context (like, is this part of an ASP.NET application?) **and** if you changed the title to something that succintly (and ideally wittingly) describes what the code is doing, not what you want out of a code review. I would also recommend including the method's signature, and heck, why not the entire class.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using an HTML templating engine instead of building up HTML via string concatenation. Also, not using inline styles or tables for layout.

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace notes.Count() > 0 with notes.Any()
2. Replace

   ```
   foreach (var item in notes)
    { 
        NoteList.Add(new NoteModel
        {
            Note1 = "<tr id=\"" + item.ID + "\" class=\"trPregame\"><td style=\"text-align:left; width:100%;\" id=\"notesonly\">" + item.Note1 + "</td></tr>",
        });
    }
   ```

   with

   ```
   NoteList.AddRange(notes.Select(item=> 
       new NoteModel { Note1 = "<tr id=\"" + item.ID + "\" class=\"trPregame\"><td style=\"text-align:left; width:100%;\" id=\"notesonly\">" + item.Note1 + "</td></tr>"}
   ));
   ```

Do you use Resharper? It helps a lot!

I noteced, that statements in if (sort== ...) are the same, so replace it with:

```
IList<NoteModel2> partial3 = new List<NoteModel2>();
foreach (var i in partial)
{
    partial3.Add(new NoteModel2
    {
        ID = i.ID,
        Note1 = i.Note1,
        Note2 = Regex.Replace(i.Note1.Trim(), @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty),
        Rank = (int)i.Rank
    });
}

IList<NoteModel2> notes;
if (sort == "none")
{
    notes = partial.OrderBy(x => x.Rank).OrderBy(x => x.Stat).OrderByDescending(x => x.Note_Strength_Value).Skip(startIndex).Take(BlockSize).ToList();

}
if (sort == "ascending")
{
    notes = partial3.OrderBy(x => x.Note2).Skip(startIndex).Take(BlockSize).ToList();        
}
else
{
    notes = partial3.OrderByDescending(x => x.Note2).Skip(startIndex).Take(BlockSize).ToList();    
}

NoteList.Clear();
if (notes.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var item in notes)
    {
        NoteList.Add(new NoteModel
        {
            Note1 = "<tr id=\"" + item.ID + "\" class=\"trPregame\"><td style=\"text-align:left; width:100%;\" id=\"notesonly\">" + item.Note1 + "</td></tr>",
        });
    }
}
else
{
    NoteList.Add(new NoteModel
    {
        Note1 = "<tr id=\"noresult\"><td colspan=\"1\" style=\"text-align:center\"><b>No Results Found!</b></td></tr>"
    });
}
```